# How do i insert a line in front of a previous line using regex on notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

For example, I would like to following list:

```
E|MG000|HIST|062575|08012019|062575|MG003
L|22WBM3|1|1871.1
E|MG000|HIST|020590|31012019|020590|MG003
L|10B771D015|-4|8.488
E|MG000|HIST|062575|21022019|062575|MG003
L|22WBM3|-1|1871.1
```

to look like this:

```
E|MG000|HIST|062575|08012019|062575|MG003 - L|22WBM3|1|1871.1
E|MG000|HIST|020590|31012019|020590|MG003 - L|10B771D015|-4|8.488
E|MG000|HIST|062575|21022019|062575|MG003 - L|22WBM3|-1|1871.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=L)`
- Replace with: `-`  (space hyphen space)
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    L         # letter L
)           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `(?m)^(E\|(?:(?!L\|).)+)\s+^(L\|.*(?:\r?\n)?)`
Replace `$1 - $2`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/PelI2g/1)